# Bootstrap right navibar messy how to fix this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add the

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mean Office</a>
   </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="" title="">Other contacts</a></li>
    <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a ng-href="#" ng-click='main.doLogout()'>Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
  </div>
```

In the above example, my Logout button is going outside of the nav bar. what is wrong here? how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: CSS - code?  I am not write any css code for mine. Just using the libraray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking navbar in side `.container class` and again the same `container class` taken after `.navbar class` as BOOTSTRAP container class have fixed width 1140px + 30px padding for large view so your navbar overflow outside it parent container.

[`body > .container > .navbar > .container`]

To resolve it you have to remove first `.container` and put `<nav class='navbar'>` directly to body tag and put container or container-fluid inside of navbar.

change to [`body > .navbar > .container OR .container-fluid`]

ONE MORE THING TO SAY

[**Practice makes perfect**]

Answer (score 1):

It is not going outside of the navbar. You have nested two container. The padding in `container`plays the part here.

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
```

`container` in bootstrap is `1170px` width having `padding-right:15px , padding-left:15px` .( I am viewing it in a screen resoultion > 1200px) .Your navbar have a total space of `1140px` now (1170px - 30px = 1140px) which has a background colore property.  As you again adding a container , It is occupying a space of 1170px now which exceeds 1140px. So in both side , a extra 15px white space gote added. Furher , The nested "`navbar-right`" has "`margin-right:-15px`" that push your `nav` further.

Simply construct this way :

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mean Office</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
        <li><a href="" title="">Other contacts</a></li>
        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a ng-href="#" ng-click='main.doLogout()'>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how a bootstrap navbar is made:

Navbar with no `container` wrapping it, but a `container-fluid` inside it:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mean Office</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="" title="">Other contacts</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a ng-href="#" ng-click='main.doLogout()'>Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

P.S.: view the results in full page for better viewing